# Style or Remove an element that has been added using CSS by using more CSS

Tags: css, menu, vaadin

I have the following HTML and CSS, which is generated by Vaadin framework:

```
<div class="v-slot">
<div class="v-splitpanel-horizontal v-widget v-has-width" style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div class="v-splitpanel-first-container v-scrollable" style="height: 100%; width: 90px;">
            <div tabindex="0" class="v-menubar v-widget v-has-width" style="width: 90px;">
              <span class="v-menubar-menuitem v-menubar-menuitem-menulevel0 v-menubar-menuitem-selected" style="color: transparent;">
                  ::before
                  <span class="v-menubar-submenu-indicator" style="color: yellow;">►</span>
                  <span class="v-menubar-menuitem-caption" style="color: red;">
                  <span class="v-icon Vaadin-Icons"></span></span>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.v-menubar > .v-menubar-menuitem:before {
    content: ">";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

The `:before` adds an Indicator which I want to remove or hide.

It seems impossible for me to select just the element in `:before` so I can keep the Menu text but remove the indicator.

How can I modify or remove something in a `:before` using CSS?

Comment: Do you want to remove the ">" when hovering over the menu item that contains the pseudo element?

Comment: No I want to remove it always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons I don't understand, `:before` doesn't work, but `:after` does. It makes sense since the indicator is displayed after the icon.

```
.v-menubar > .v-menubar-menuitem-menulevel0 .v-menubar-menuitem-caption:after {
    content: "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the content by setting it to "", like so:

```
.v-menubar > .v-menubar-menuitem:before {
   content: "";
}
```

this will remove the ">" Icon from your menu.